# How to convert "GMT+5.5_(INDIA) " into timezone region "Asia/Kolkata"

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, timezone

I want to know how to derive a timezone name from a timezone offset. For example, if I have `"GMT-07_(PDT)` I should be getting `America/Los_Angeles` returned. Likewise, `GMT+5.5_(INDIA)` should return `Asia/Kolkata` and `GMT+09_(JAPAN)` should return `Asia/Tokyo`.

I have to implement this in Oracle.

Comment: @RonnieOosting - this problem is far from trivial to solve. This seems like a case where it's reasonable for a Seeker to not know how to start.

Answer (score 2):

A combination of some string manipulation and the following should get you close

- the function [`TZ_OFFSET()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/TZ_OFFSET.html#GUID-D2007072-34C2-4971-BD2B-64D93A3D7A31), which returns an offset based on the time zone region name
- the system view [`V$TIMEZONE_NAMES`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/refrn/V-TIMEZONE_NAMES.html), which has the time zone region and abbreviation

First, you'll need to extract the provided offset:

```
select regexp_replace( 'GMT+5.5_(INDIA)'
                     , '[[:alpha:]]{3}(-|\+)(\d+)(\.(\d+))?.*'
                     , '\1\2\3')
  from dual
```

Then, you need to convert this into the proper format. Assuming the regular expression provided you something named `s` then:

```
with setup as (
select to_number(s) as n from ...
       )
    select case when n < 0 then '-' else '+' end 
           || lpad(trunc(n), 2, '0') 
           || ':' 
           || lpad((n - trunc(n)) * 60, 2, '0') as offset
      from dual
```

Lastly, you can use this to query our view using `TZ_OFFSET` to return *all* valid timezone regions.

```
select tzname
  from v$timezone_names
 where tzoffset(tzname) = :offset
```

If you want to pick one timezone region you'll need to create some additional logic that describes which one you wish to pick.

In a single query this is going to look ugly, but would be something like

```
with strip_characters as (
select to_number(regexp_replace( 'GMT+5.5_(INDIA)'
                               , '[[:alpha:]]{3}(-|\+)(\d+)(\.(\d+))?.*'
                               , '\1\2\3'))
  from dual
       )
, setup as (
select case when n < 0 then '-' else '+' end 
       || lpad(trunc(n), 2, '0') 
       || ':' 
       || lpad((n - trunc(n)) * 60, 2, '0') as offset
  from strip_characters
       )
select t.tzname
  from v$timezone_names t
  join setup s
 where tzoffset(t.tzname) = s.offset
```

Comment: Seems from the linked docs that `TZ_OFFSET` doesn't take a timestamp input, so it only returns the current standard-time offset.  Also, not sure how the example in the docs for `V$TIMEZONE` can work in that is shows `TZABBREV` returning they daylight abbreviation and no column to give the standard abbreviation?

Comment: `TZ_OFFSET()` returns the offset based on the timezone region and, I assume, the daylight saving status at query execution time.`V$TIMEZONE_NAMES` contains the timezone region as many times as necessary. Your [first example of `America/Los_Angeles` exists with 5 different timezones in Oracle 11.2](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=e79257fdd828777ea1eb1e2641dbf6b9). This answer certainly isn't perfect - but it's as close to what the OP is after as I can get. Maybe they'll be lucky and have summer time in the abbreviations in the data.

Comment: Oh, so `TZ_OFFSET` implies *now* as it's basis?  That's interesting - and also problematic when working over data recorded previously.  Thanks for the fiddle on `V$TIMEZONE_NAMES`.  That shows all of the abbreviations that might apply over the lifetime of that time zone - which makes sense, but would be more useful if there was a function that took the tzname and a timestamp to give you the appropriate tzabbrev.  Not sure if that exists in Oracle or not.

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking for is not possible for all cases in a reliable manner. Any attempt would be biased towards a specific worldview.

For example, you gave `GMT-07_(PDT)` and said that it should be `America/Los_Angeles`.  That implies that the US's time zone identifiers are somehow more important.  All of the following canonical zone identifiers use Pacific Daylight Time and GMT-07:

- `America/Los_Angeles`  (USA)
- `America/Tijuana`      (Mexico)
- `America/Vancouver`    (Canada)
- `America/Dawson`       (Canada)
- `America/Whitehorse`   (Canada)

Even with a US-centric worldview, and limiting to modern times, it still doesn't work. Consider another example: `GMT-07_(MST)`.  Is that `America/Denver` or `America/Phoenix`?  Denver represents a zone that transitions between -7 and -6 for daylight saving time, but Phoenix represent a zone that is in -7 year-round without daylight saving time.

These are relatively simple examples.  Consider if you had `GMT+01_(CET)`.  The number of discrepancies to contend with there are to numerous to list.

Also consider that not every time zone has a meaningful abbreviation, and that time zone abbreviations are not consistent (ex: HST vs HAST) and are often ambiguous (ex: CST).

In general, one can determine an offset (and sometimes an abbreviation) from a time zone identifier for a specific point in time, but the reverse direction is not achievable.

See also "Time Zone != Offset" in [the timezone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info).

Comment: Purely out of interest would you mind listing one of the discrepancies with `GMT+01_(CET)`? That seems relatively simple to me as CET means, currently, Central European Time, (and distinctly not CEST) which has a UTC offset of +01:00. There are two facts, which corroborate each other and fit reality. `GMT-07_(PDT)` seemed the example the OP provided with the least potential issues.

Comment: `Europe/Paris`, `Europe/Oslo`, `Europe/Rome`... lots more that use CET in the winter and CEST in the summer.  But also, `Africa/Tunis` and `Africa/Algiers` which use CET all year (without CEST) and call their time zone CET despite being in Africa (due to their proximity across the Mediterranean Sea).

Comment: Ah, you're talking about timezone regions. Thanks. The OP is in trouble the world over on that one unless there's some additional data in the database that can help create a decision.

Comment: Right.  That was my understanding of what the OP was looking for.  Bottom line is, it's not implementable in *any* technology platform due to the nature of the data.  The best one could due is to decide which values were important to them and map them manually.  For example, perhaps the OP has a dataset that they know contains data from businesses that operate only in certain regions.  They could limit their reverse mapping to those regions.  Or better yet, perhaps there's some other information in the dataset that can more reliably identify the time zone, such as lat/lon or city+country.

Comment: Thanks for your answer